# How to stub a function in C++ that has a return type?

Tags: c++

Assuming I want to stub a function in case I am compiling for project2, example:

```
#ifdef PROJECT1
int func(int x) {x=1;return x;}
#else
int func(int x) {}
#endif
```

This wont work as the compiler will complain that the function doesnt return an int.

But I really just want to stub the function, I basically, want to have it nulled whenever it is called.

To fix this I basically have to change the code to:

```
#ifdef PROJECT1
int func(int x) {x=1;return x;}
#else
int func(int x) {return (int)0;}
#endif
```

Is there a way to better handle this?

Comment: How would you want `auto foo = func(42);` handled?

Comment: hmmm, good point.

Comment: If  you're still including `func()` when building `PROJECT2` what is the expected behavior if you call it?  Should it be called at all?

Comment: See the problem is I want to use the same source code, but only ignore this function when compiling project2, so I agree with the first commenter now that in cases where we are actually using the return value in PROJECT1 this has to be solved when compiling for PROJECT2

Comment: something like `ASSERT`?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to ignore func during project two build? What happens if it or the variable that is assigned the result is used? Wont this produce undefined/unwanted consequences in your code? Surely what you are trying to do has a better way, even if that means having two separate repositories for different projects.

*Iff removing every call of func during build 2 is permissible, ei it still compiles*, you could do some form of macro magic. Although this is a bad idea for anything outside of some inhouse experimentation.

```
#ifdef PROJECT1 
  int func(int x) {x=1; return x;}

  #define FUNC(x) func(x)/* Call the function */ 

  #define FUNC_ASSIGN(x, var) var = func(x)/* Call the function and store result in var*/ 

#else 

  #define FUNC(x)/* NULLED OUT */ 

  #define FUNC_ASSIGN(x, var)/* NULLED OUT */  

#endif

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int x = 2;
  FUNC_ASSIGN(5, x);
  std::cout << x;

  return 1;
}
```

The program will print a different result depending on if PROJECT1 is defined. Notice that this way you cannot declare and assign a variable directly `auto x = func(1)`. This is because if we NULL out func, what will happen if you use x?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your stub-able functions all return an `int` and you want them to become no-ops that return 0 when stubbed-out, a pattern like this would be fairly succinct:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_STUBS
# define STUB_CHECK return 0
#else
# define STUB_CHECK
#endif

int func(int x)
{
   STUB_CHECK;

   x = 1;
   return x;
}
```

If you need to be able to specify different/non-zero values for the stubbed-out-functions to return, you could extend the STUB_CHECK macro to take an argument:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_STUBS
# define STUB_CHECK(x) return x
#else
# define STUB_CHECK(x)
#endif

int func(int x)
{
   STUB_CHECK(6);

   x = 1;
   return x;
}
```